# Reverse Array C

Tags: c, arrays, reverse

I have a problem for the below function.

```
void reverseAr1D(int ar[], int size)
{
   int temp[size], j = 0;

   for(int i = size - 1; i > -1; i--)
   {
       temp[j] = ar[i];
       j++;
   }

   j = 0;

   for(int i = size - 1; i >- 1; i--)
   {
       *(ar + j) = *(temp + i);
       j++;
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       printf("%d ", temp[i]);
 }
```

I would like to reverse every element in the array `ar[]`. I tried to copy reversely to another array `temp[]`. Then copy the `temp[]` back to `ar[]`. I tried but is not working. Below is my code. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printReverse1(int ar[], int size);
void printReverse2(int ar[], int size);
void reverseAr1D(int ar[], int size);

int main()
{
    int ar[10];
    int size, i;

    printf("Enter array size: \n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("Enter %d data: \n", size);

    for (i = 0; i <= size - 1; i++)
        scanf("%d", &ar[i]);

    printReverse1(ar, size);
    printReverse2(ar, size);

    reverseAr1D(ar, size);
    printf("reverseAr1D(): ");

    if (size > 0) 
    {
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            printf("%d ", ar[i]);
    }

    return 0;
 }



  void printReverse1(int ar[], int size)
{
 /* using index – Write your program code here */
  printf("printReverse1(): ");
  for(int i=size-1;i>-1;i--){

  printf(" %d ",ar[i]);
 }
 printf("\n");
 }



 void printReverse2(int ar[], int size)
 {
 /* using pointer – Write your program code here */
   printf("printReverse2(): ");
  for(int i=size-1;i>-1;i--){

  printf(" %d ",*(ar+i));
 }
 printf("\n");
}



void reverseAr1D(int ar[ ], int size)
{
 /* Write your program code here */
 int temp[size],j=0;
 for(int i=size-1;i>-1;i--){

 temp[j]=ar[i];


 j++;
 }
 j=0;
 for(int i=size-1;i>-1;i--){

 *(ar+j)=*(temp+i);


 j++;
 }
 for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
 printf("%d ", temp[i]);

 }
```

Comment: This seems like the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: In what way is your code not working?

Comment: elements in ar[] is not reverse.

Comment: At first glance you're reversing it twice: you reverse them as you copy them into temp and then reverse them again as you copy them back. So no change overall.

Comment: One of the important things in coding is to use proper indentation. This makes your code more readable and also you can understand the flow better.

Comment: FWIW, the classic C reverse something algorithm is: i = 0, j = size -1; while (j > i) { swap elements i and j; ++i; --j; }.

Comment: Thanks @Rup. Sorry for my silly mistakes

Comment: No problem - it's easily done!

Comment: I have downvoted this post for horrible formatting. Since SO disallows me to say "-1", I am offering specific guidance - format your code better next time.

Comment: Start by writing a `swap` function. This avoids the need to make a copy of the entire thing (which could be huge). Also, it's easier to use array syntax than pointer arithmetic for this kind of task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing in your `reverseAr1D` function is to copy the already reversed elements in `temp` in the reversed order into `ar`. So you will end up with the original order of elements.

In your `reverseAr1D` function you have to change the second `for` loop to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
 *(ar + j) = *(temp + i);
  j++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

May be, the fastest way to do it:

```
 int *front_p, *back_p;
 for(front_p=&ar[0], back_p=&ar[size-1]; front_p < back_p; ++front_p, --back_p) {
     tmp=*back_p; *back_p=*front_p; *front_p=tmp; 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a lot of code to reverse an array of integers. Here's the classic way:

```
void arrayReverse(int* array, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (size / 2); i++) {
        int swap = array[size - 1 - i];
        array[size - 1 - i] = array[i];
        array[i] = swap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5
void main(){
    int i,j,temp,array[SIZE]={1,2,3,4,5},k;

    for(i=0,j=SIZE-1;i<j;i++,j--){
        temp=array[i];
        array[i]=array[j];
        array[j]=temp;
    }   

    for(k=0;k<SIZE;k++){
        printf("%d\n",array[k]);
    }
}
```